# error in creating gpu google instance

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, gpu, google-cloud-platform

I have tried creating GPU instance in Google Cloud Platform but every time I try to create an instance it shows "You've reached your limit of 0 GPUs NVIDIA K80".

I am trying to create an instance with 4 vCPU, 8-15 gb memory, 1 GPU and in us-east1-c/us-west1-b.

Please help for the following.

Answer (score 15):

Follow all the steps in specified order, because otherwise GPUs won't be seen in Quotas page.

You need to go to the Quotas part of IAM & Admin:
https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/iam-admin/iam/quotas
Here, in Quota type, you should select "All quotas" and find GPU quotas for your region. Then, you hit "Edit Quotas" button on the top of the page, select GPU quotas for your region and proceed with the steps on the right menu. Hope this helps.

Comment: Cant find GPU on the list

Comment: make sure you select the correct filters, i.e. region. Not all regions have gpus available. The described steps worked perfectly for me (us-east1).

Comment: The url is not valid anymore.

Comment: Hi, I face the same problem.  I increased the quota for GPU and I got a mail also that the quota was increased.  But when I give the command datalab beta create-gpu <name> --zone us-west1-b, it throws an error

- Quota 'NVIDIA_K80_GPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region us-west1.

Comment: How long does it take to get "approval" on the quota increase request?  Who is doing this approval?  A person?  A bot?

Comment: I can answer my own question I sent last night.  It took about 2 hours for me to get my "approval".  Other posts I saw said it would go quick, but I guess "quick" is relative and maybe they were backed up.  Seems funny to me that I have to request to give them a lot more money!

Comment: Frustrating experience as a first time user!

Answer (score 4):

you cannot addu gpu's without upgrading your account .May be that is thwarting you. Here is the link for documentation https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions