# Cannot Extend GPU Quota on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-compute-engine

I am using Google Cloud for development and training of deep neural networks.  I've reached the limits of what I can do with CPUs and now need to create and instance with one or more GPUs.

I've [followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294744/error-in-creating-gpu-google-instance) the instructions from [multiple sources](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gce-discussion/gpu$20quota%7Csort:date).  As the instance was being created I received a notification that my quota for my region (us-west1) was zero and to request an increase.

I did so and received the confirmation email within minutes.  However, when I then attempted to recreate the instance I was again met with the quota increase error.

I submitted another request (same region) but heard nothing.

I tried in a different region, again requesting a quota increase, but heard nothing.  I did this 6 times and -- as you might have guessed -- neither received a confirmation email nor was I able to create my instance.

I tried the hack of using Chrome in Incognito mode, but no joy.

This *was* an issue a few months ago, at least judging from the S/O and Google forum posts.  I would think that by now it would be fixed.

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm totally stuck

NB: Cross-posted to the [gce-discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/BF1OYfWTdvM)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should contact the [Google Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) for this kind of issues.

Open a case asking why your quota increase has not been applied and I am sure they are going to solve this in some days or at least to tell you why your request was declined.

> Notice that quoting from the official [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#gpus) "Free Trial accounts do not receive GPU quota by default."

Disclaimer: I work for the Google Cloud Support.

Comment: I have been requesting GPU Quota for a week, they said I don't have enough history. any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: I am not working for Google Cloud Support anymore, anyway they are ultimately the one deciding, so the only think you can do is convincing them