# Google Compute Engine can't find GPU even though quota exists

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I requested and received my quota for a preemptible K80 GPU.
[image]

In the Console I can see this quota available (in region 'us-east1'). However, my VM in the same region is unable to find this GPU:

> tensorflow-1-vm: {"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"404","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":404,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"The resource 'projects/dlp-project-212017/zones/us-east1-b/acceleratorTypes/nvidia-tesla-k80' was not found","reason":"notFound"}],"message":"The resource 'projects/dlp-project-212017/zones/us-east1-b/acceleratorTypes/nvidia-tesla-k80' was not found","statusMessage":"Not Found","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/dlp-project-212017/zones/us-east1-b/instances","httpMethod":"POST"}}

When I use the command-line to check if I have quota, I also see that I **do not** have available quota.
[image]

Anyone knows how to handle these discrepancies? Mainly, how do I run my VM with my GPU now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a support issue. Not a programming question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon you're right, but I've only posted this after seeing similar posts received answer, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294744/error-in-creating-gpu-google-instance

If you have a different place I should refer to, please send me there

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The nvidia-tesla-k80 GPu is not available on the zone "us-east1-b" it just available on these zones :

```
us-west1-b
us-central1-a
us-central1-c
us-east1-c
us-east1-d
europe-west1-b
europe-west1-d
asia-east1-a
asia-east1-b
```

You can check this Google Document for the [Availability Zone of each type of GPU](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/)